# Labeling edges/borders of polygons using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, labeling, administrative-boundaries

How would I label polygon features, such as Counties, by its edge in ArcMap 10.1?

This is similar to what one might find in a street atlas.

For instance, have there are two counties (Lamb and Castro), at the same spot I want the labels to be inside along the boundary in the respective counties.

Comment: Can you post an image of the effect you want?

Comment: Did the Answer below work for you?

Answer (score 8):

[At 10.1](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//016w0000002n000000),

> The Maplex for ArcGIS extension functionality has been moved into the
>   core ArcGIS for Desktop product and is referred to as the Maplex Label
>   Engine.

so getting the effect you want is easy.

On the **Data Frame Properties** change Label Engine from Standard label Engine to **Maplex Label Engine**.

On the **Layer Properties** go to the **Labels** tab, open the **Placement Properties** and under General change Regular Placement to **Boundary Placement**.

Answer (score 1):

For ArcGIS 10.0:

[image: example]

> Steps:
>
> ```
> 1. Click the Label Manager button Label Manager on the Labeling toolbar.
> 2. Check the check box next to the layer you want to label.
> 3. Choose a label class under the layer.
> 4. Click the Properties button.
> 5. Click the Label Position tab.
> 6. Choose River Placement from the drop-down list.
>    The label position can change when you choose the River Placement style. This is because there are two placement positions for contour features: Curved and Offset Curved.
> 7. Click OK to close all dialog boxes.
> ```
>
> TipTip: You can also open the Placement Properties dialog box by
> clicking the Placement Properties button on the Labels tab of the
> Layer Properties dialog box for the layer you want to label.

source: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//003s00000026000000.htm